# How can GRPC interceptors extract data from message and pass to each other?

Tags: java, interceptor, grpc

I have 2 GRPC interceptors:

#1 extracts some data from the message

#2 validates the data and closes call with error if invalid

How can interceptor #1 extract some data from the message, put it into `Context` and call interceptor #2 (using `Contexts.interceptCall(context, call, headers, next)` with modified `Context` instance)?

The problem is that i can't access message in overriden

```
<ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
      ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
      Metadata headers,
      ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next)
```

Using `ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener` does not help as `interceptCall()` of interceptor #2 is called before `onMessage()` of interceptor #1.

```
private Object msg;
private <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCallAfterMessage(
        final ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
        Metadata headers,
        ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
      Context context = Context.current().withValue("msg", msg); // error: msg is not yet extracted !
      return Contexts.interceptCall(context, call, headers, next);
}
...
new ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener(
    interceptCallAfterMessage(call, headers, next)) { // happens first
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Object message) {
        msg = message; // happens second
        super.onMessage(message);
    }
};
```